# Trying to send header in node

Tags: node.js, header, response

I'm trying to access an api that requires me to send some information in the header in the `GET` request as described in the image below.

[image]

I have my code set up like this, but I'm getting a `resp has no method setter` error. I've read in various posts and seen examples in other languages where this is done, but I can't quite figure it out in node.

```
https.get(url, function(resp){
                    resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "json/application");
                    resp.setHeader("Authorization", Key);

                    resp.on('data', function(chunk){
                        sentStr += chunk;
                    });

                    resp.on('end', function(){
                        console.log(sentStr);
                    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the headers for the response, while the request is the one that needs to be set. `http` and `https` takes either the URL or a set of options to start the call. here is an example

```
 var https = require('https');

 var options = {
     hostname: "www.google.com",
     port: 443,
     path: '/',
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
         "Content-Type": "json/application"
         "Authorization" : "KEY YOU NEED TO SUPPORT"
     }
 }

 https.get(options, function(res) {
       console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
         console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

           res.on('data', function(d) {
                   process.stdout.write(d);
                     });

 }).on('error', function(e) {
       console.error(e);
 });
```